# link to a random custom post while excluding current post

Tags: custom-post-types, exclude

I am using the below code to create a link from a custom post to another random custom post.

```
<?php $args=array('post_type'=>'projects', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'1'); $projects=new WP_Query($args); while ($projects->have_posts()) : $projects->the_post(); ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Another Project</a> 
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

however, the link is still picking up the current post in its random selection so would like to try and exclude the current post somehow.

Answer (score 3):

On your argument, exclude the current post using `post__not_in`

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'=>'projects', 
    'orderby'=>'rand', 
    'posts_per_page'=>'1', 
    'post__not_in'=> array( get_the_ID() )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction but was slightly off. Needed to be set in an array and seems to be working. 'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()),